# How to convert subset of users into a content type?

Tags: users

I have a Google Map set on view of the node type. I am mapping several piece pieces of content on that map (group meeting locations, organization meeting places, etc). I would also like to be able to add my users to this map but I'm not given "users" as a content type in my list of options.

For this reason I want to take a subset of my users and create a new content type to add to the map. I know I could map a view the users, so it looks like users are a special content type.

So, it seem like the best approach is to create a content type based on a subset of my users (users that aren't admins, or who register under member, chapter head, etc roles).

I realize I could do this manually, and then have the admin add the users that match the criteria, but that seems like a work around, and fairly tedious.

With new users, I could probably hack together a rule that populates the content type from the profile fields, but I have a substantial amount of registered users already.

So, is there some way to populate a content type with user fields? Such that the content type was populated with the fields from every user of a particular role.

Comment: Is there something both have in common? Like taxonomy term for example?

Comment: Can you EDIT your question to better explain what that "MAP" is about: what exactly is that, and how should it be visiualized? Also, I think the "convert" in your title is not the right word to use, you don't want to do something equivalent to the node_convert module (I guess), but using a user profile as input to "convert" it to another content type ... or am I wrong (and is THAT exactly what you want to do)?

Comment: essentially yes, I'd like to do something like FOR EVERY USER WITH ROLE = MEMBER add it to Member content type.

Comment: It occurs to me that one way to do this would be to grab the user table from the dbase, filter down to what I want, and add them to the content type with feeds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content types are not optimal for this use case. Use entities instead.

Create an appropriate user entity to map. You can have several bundles within it to represent any relevant different types of users.

Then you will need to relate the user entities to the actual users. It's up to you how you do the relating. You can use entity references or the relation module.

Comment: this is a very generic answer, but this is the track I'm on. can you elaborate